# using same boot diagnostics storage account for multiple virtual machine's

Tags: azure, azure-rm-template

I'm trying to provision 30 vm's with different copyindex(),with different RG's and each RG having single diagnostic storage account. while running script it is getting failed different vm creation for different run's

code": "Conflict"

StorageAccountOperationInProgress

message:An operation is currently performing on this storage account that requires exclusive access.

Comment: how about making creation of vms sequential, not parallel?

Comment: sequential also same issue

Comment: that cant be, unless there's something else going on